# Magic Explanation of Minecrafts infinite water source

Tags: magic

There is no realistic way to explain Minecrafts infinite water source as far as I know. So I'm searching for the magic behind Minecraft.
The source has the abilities:

- It's somehow infinite water flowing out of the source
- The water somehow disappears when it has no other way to go or the horizontal distance is too far; it doesn't stack.
- Humans can swim waterfalls of this special water up
- Humans can't bottle the special water, but just the source
- When two sources are near, they create another new source
- Humans can't breathe in this special water
- The special water destructs plants

Is there an 'reasonable' explanation behind this behavior?

PS: Feel free to edit if I missed something

Comment: There is a SE dedicated to videogames. Why not asking there? I see no worldbuilding in this question.

Answer (score 3):

That is not water, that's aether.

Think of it. You don't die of dehydration for lack of contact or lack of ingestion of it. It comes from another world (you can literally pull it out of your... portable source in a bucket).  It grants any creature the ability to fly and can combine elementally with fire (in the form of lava) to form earth (in the form of obsidian).

You are dealing with some really weird alchemy there.

Comment: but why can't human bottle aether, and why do the sources connect, why does it disappear?

Comment: @Jannis because [tag:magic]. If you overanalyze it, it becomes science instead.

Comment: @Renan : The problem with many questions on this site is The Heterodyne adjunct to Clarke’s Third Law: [Any sufficiently analysed magic is indistinguishable from science](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20081205#.XCUCX6TLeEc)